# How can i execute an CREATE Oracle SQL statement in a SELECT?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

Here is the SQL:

```
    select 'create table XX_' || replace(replace(trim(table_id),'-','_'),'%','X') || '_LOOKUP as select * from prn_tcodes where trim(table_id) = ''' || trim(table_id) || ''';'
from  prn_tcodes
group by table_id;
```

I want the resulted SQL statements to be executed, is there a way?

I'm using Oracle 10g

Thank you,,,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spool your above script to a file, then execute that file.

```
spool myoutput.sql

-- Your SQL here

spool off;
@myoutput;
```

Comment: Thank you it worked but without the @myoutput, its saying the statement wasn't terminated correctly.
What does it do anyway?

Comment: The `spool` command instructs SQL*Plus (I'm assuming you're using SQL*Plus) to write all output to the file that you specify, as well as echoing to the screen; `spool off` closes the file. The `@` operator executes an SQL file, by filename... If you're getting that error, possibly I have been too liberal with semi-colons ;) or there's something wrong with your generated SQL: have a look at the myoutput.sql file and check it's as you expect.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to spooling you can run that as an anonymous PL/SQL block (not tested!)

```
DECLARE 
  cursor all_codes 
      select 'create table XX_' || 
             replace(replace(trim(table_id),'-','_'),'%','X') || 
             '_LOOKUP as select * from prn_tcodes where trim(table_id) = ''' ||
             trim(table_id) as sql_stmt
      from  prn_tcodes
      group by table_id;

   rec all_codes%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
   FOR rec IN get_objects LOOP
   BEGIN
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE rec.sql_stmt;
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

(Note that the generated statement does not include the trailing `;` any more)

Answer (score 0):

You want to execute dynamic SQL, so check out `execute immediate` (see more info [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/dynamic.htm#i13130) and [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/executeimmediate_statement.htm)).